# Django, catch and return arbitrary subpath in a url

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a url path defined like this:

```
path("/media/private/<path>", PrivateDocumentView.as_view()),
```

Expecting this to catch urls of the form:

```
/media/private/some/path/to/some/file.pdf
```

But it doesn't.

I've tried this:

```
re_path(r"^/media/private/(?P<path>.*)$", PrivateDocumentView.as_view()),
```

But that also doesn't work. Just a 404 error, as the url is not matching.

I know it looks like I'm trying to serve static files from django itself, which is a sacking offence, but I'm not, honestly!

Comment: You don't need the leading `/`, maybe that's the reason? `re_path(r"^media/private/(?P<path>.*)$" ...`

Comment: @C14L That was dumb of me... Thank you! You want to put that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the leading `/`, maybe that's the reason?

```
re_path(r"^media/private/(?P<path>.*)$" ...
```